# How do I find the highest number from the database in PROLOG for a specified person?

Tags: prolog

I have been assigned to do some work on PROLOG, I have made a very good attempt at one question where I was suppose to find the largest number of pages for a single article by a certain author.

What I have so far is:

```
A= Author
P = Pages

Pages(A,N) :- Database(A,_,_,_,N,_).
getpages(X) :- findall(A,pages(_,A),X).
getauthor(X) :- findall(A,pages(A,_),X).

printlist([A|N]) :- print(A), nl,pages(A,N).
```

Once I run a query for findall I get the numbers of pages but not in descending order, showing the highest value, how do I do that?

I have an idea of using sumlist and/or printlist somehow.

Also how do I find something in a database Starting with 'abc' or whatever.. I know in sql you have a function to do that, but how is it done in PROLOG? I want to find all the articles starting with 'IEEE'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering how to print a list in ascending order, you just have to sort it first. There is a builtin predicate,  `sort/2`, that you can use for sorting a list in ascending order.
Check the [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/2) documentation for details. If there are possible duplicates that you don't want to eliminate, use `msort/2` instead.

You could write a predicate that gets the pages in ascending order like this:

```
getpages_sorted(X) :- findall(A, pages(_, A), Unsorted), sort(Unsorted, X).
```

It would also be wise to choose representative names for your variables, code clarity plays an integral part at debugging in prolog.

Comment: What if I want to find it in the descending order? also, I don't understand how to use he sort(Unsorted,X). would this implement the first answer produced from the findall and then unsort the X list?.

Comment: If you need it in descending order, sort and then reverse. 
`sort(Unsorted, X)` sorts the result that `findall/3` has come up with, which of course is unsorted, and X is now your sorted list. If you still have trouble understanding, I recommend reading carefully through a prolog tutorial on lists and unification.

Comment: Okay, I understand the concept of having to reverse the list , but what I don't understand is the query , would I run it from the rev_list? Meaning I'll have to append the lists together ?

Comment: No, it's something like this:
`sort(Unsorted, Sorted), reverse(Sorted, Reversed)`

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'm going to have to go over the Reverse chapter as I am not fully understanding how to implement the rule of it with regards to my scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[setof](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions)/3 instead of findall/3 will do, but you have to qualify free variables *scope* to properly use it, since variables binding plays a very important role in Prolog *execution*:

```
getpages(X) :- setof(A,S^pages(S,A),X).
```

library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) will put in your hands more constructs ready to use, similar to what's available in SQL, but you should first try to understand well setof/3.

Prolog doesn't have 'select ... where ... LIKE ...'. Symbols are used for identity, while in SQL (intended as relational calculus), identity is by *record*. This is a shortcoming when moving logic from relational RDBMs to Prolog, similar to the case insensitiveness that RDBMs implement. A COLLATION it's not a concept of Prolog...

So, when you ask

> how do I find something in a database Starting with 'abc' or whatever..

you should implement your own matching algorithm, for instance

```
page(Author, _Title) :- sub_atom(Author,_,_,_,abc).
```

would match any page having 'abc' in Author atom, similar to

```
select Author from page where Author like '%abc%'
```

*edit* [sub_atom](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sub_atom/5)/5 it's rather powerful: for instance, to peek atoms *starting* with abc

```
1 ?- sub_atom(abcd,0,_,_,abc).
true.

2 ?- sub_atom(zabcd,0,_,_,abc).
false.
```

Comment: From testing out your rule, I couldn't really understand how it would be implemeneted to find all the titles starting with IEEE.